# How to add a bound method to an object that survives pickling in python?

Tags: python, function, object, pickle

I am trying to carry out the following steps:

1. create an **object foo** from **class A**
2. add a **function bar** to **object foo** at runtime
3. **pickle** object **foo** (which now contains the function **bar**)
4. load object **foo** with **pickle** and execute the function **foo.bar**

Until Step 3, it all goes fine. Step 4 fails.

Here is the code I was using:

create.py

```
import pickle
class A():
    pass

foo = A()

def bar():
    print('hello')

foo.bar = bar.__get__(foo)

with open('test.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(foo, f)
```

running foo.bar tells me, that bar is now a bound method of the A object:

foo.bar

*bound method bar of <**main**.A object at 0x000002014B8250F0>*

use.py

```
import pickle
f = open('test.pkl', 'rb')
foo = pickle.load(f)
foo.bar()
```

Execution use.py leads to the following error message:
[image]

Any ideas, what would be the best way to proceed here? My goal in simple terms is to have some sort of storable object that can be loaded from the outside and allows access to the foo and also can exectue bar. Hence, bar does not necessarily have to be part of the foo object, I just thought it would be a neat way. Thanks for help!

Comment: Pickle doesn't dump code, and neither should you. Mind sharing the X of your [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with us? (i.e. Why do you think you need to do this?)

Comment: Sure, this is the 'X': I am building a model in scikit learn which is then stored as pickle object. The reason for this is that the model is build in a train environment but must be run in a prod environment where it has to be copied into. Once the model is loaded (which works fine), it needs to know where to get its data from. This is why I would like to attach the bar function to the model which then loads the data. You might ask why the model does not contain the get_data in the first place. The reason is that the modelling and data prep are two seperate work streams. I hope this helps.

Comment: It sounds odd that you're loading an instance which then loads more data in a 2nd step, but then again it's difficult to judge your program's architecture without knowing anything about it. But anyway, leaving that aside, what you're currently doing is this: You're dumping an object for the sole purpose of it being used by `use.py`. However, this object doesn't implement the interface that `use.py` needs (because it doesn't have a `bar` method). Clearly, you're dumping the wrong kind of object. If `use.py` expects an object with a `bar` method, then `A` should have a `bar` method.

Comment: You have to define an interface for the `A` class and stick to it. There is no world in which dynamically adding a method to an instance is the correct solution for this problem. So I would suggest taking a step back, and rethinking your architecture.

Comment: True, there must be another way. Simply all I need is a means to transport the model plus the way to get data between systems in a way that allows copy-pasting of models. BTW, it is a very common method in model building to train a model on data source A but in production mode, data comes from source B.

Comment: I found a way to it with only little additional programming effort. I create a container class which has foo and bar as attributes. This container class can easily be pickled and reloaded. Thanks for the discussion, that was helpul!